# Custom View not respond very well on touch events

Tags: android, view, touch-event, ondraw, viewgroup

I have a custom grid which extends ViewGroup and I have the next onLayout and measureChildrenSizes methods:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    // .. tileSide calcultion ..

    measureChildrenSizes(tileSide);
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        Square child = (Square) getChildAt(i);
        int x = child.getColumn();
        int y = child.getRow();
        child.layout(x * tileSide, y * tileSide,
                (x + 1) * tileSide, (y + 1) * tileSide);
    }   
}

private void measureChildrenSizes(int tileSide) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        measureChild(child, tileSide, tileSide);
    }
}
```

The childs (Square) are custom Views which have a custom onDraw method and the onTouch callback method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    rect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        gradient.setBounds(rect);
        gradient.draw(canvas);              

        rectangle.setStrokeWidth(0.2f);
        rectangle.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        rectangle.setColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.puzzle_foreground));
        canvas.drawRect(rect, rectangle);
        }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        requestFocus();
        changeState();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This draw a grid of Squares which side measure is tileSide. All the Squares works fine except the last column. Sometimes they don't respond.

Perhaps I'm looking for in the wrong direction.

Edit: in the emulator works fine. It fails in real Devices (tested on Sony xperia u, Samsung galaxy Ace, Samsung galaxy mini).

Comment: If you've not done it already, you should probably call `super.onLayout()` when your overridden version is called, before anything else is done.

Comment: I can't do it. onLayout() is an abstract method of the ViewGroup. There isn't an implementation on super class.

Answer (score 0):

Returning false in your `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`can cause some of the GestureDetector(if that's what you are using) methods to not be called. Try returning true there and see if it responds better.

This Android Developers page might help you:  [Making a View Interactive](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes bad touch responses can be caused by breaking cycle of managing views by Adapter in AdapterView. I have experienced the same issue when I saved
reference to views managed by AdapterView. It can cause bad response to touches.